# Javascript prompt printing new lines

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node to execute this code. What I want is to simple make a question and get the answer, but for some reason, when I print the question with a new line, in the console, while I answer the question, the console keep printing the same question, it will be easier to explain with an image:

[image]

```
var question = "test";

var answer = makeQuestion(question + "\n");

console.log("The answer is: " + answer);

function makeQuestion (question) {
    var prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
    
    var string = prompt(question);
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the new-line you are adding to your question. It works fine without:

```
var answer = makeQuestion(question);
```

---

Update:

If you want a solution that allows new line characters in the question, I would recommend the node.js built-in `readline`:

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What is your name ?\n", function(name) {
  console.log(`you said your name is ${name}`);
});
```

Comment: When I use readline, the console.log prints in the same time as the input is being read. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be due to the way `prompt-sync` implements input editing. After you type each character, it clears the current line and rewrites the prompt followed by the edited answer.

If the prompt contains any newlines, the "current line" is the part after the last newline and the input. But it still rewrites the entire prompt, so you get repeated prompts.

This is a reported issue: https://github.com/heapwolf/prompt-sync/issues/44

There's no solution other than not putting newlines in the prompt.